# Adding jQuery code to ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a project using ASP.NET Boilerplate.  I want to add more functionality by using jQuery.

I try to write a simple code such as (below) to the end of a page (such as Home.cshtml), it looks like no effect at all!  Then I try to put this code in Home.js file, nothing happens at all.  I also try to create a new .js file with the below code and link it into the project, the body color didn't turn to red!

Please help how to write jQuery on ASP.NET Boilerplate.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css('background', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Did you wrap the code in `script` tags - did you reference the external js you made - were there errors in the console?

Comment: I did wrap the code in `<script>`.  I did reference the external.js.  There is no JS error in console.

Comment: APS.NET Boilerplate is using jquery-2.1.1.min.js .  I thought there is a conflict, then I tried $.noConflict();, it didn't work, either.

Comment: did you add your script block at end of all the script files? make sure to use razor script section and add the script block in `@section Scripts{<script>$(function () {
    $('body').css('background', 'red');
});</script>}`

Comment: @ Venkata, I added the code you provide at the end of Home.cshtml, it looks ok, no error, but the background didn't turn red.  How comes?

Comment: Have you use Chrome Developer tools or Firebug for Firefox to make sure you resources are loaded? Use the "Net" tab to check for files that are not downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process to proper execution; check `@RenderSection` and `@section` in below files

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- .removed.for.brevity. -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <!-- .removed.nav.bar.for.brevity. -->

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    <!-- .removed.footer.for.brevity. -->
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <!-- .below script section will render from view cshtml. -->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**view.cshtml**

```
<!-- All your view html -->
@section Scripts {

    <script>
      $(function () { 
          $('body').css('background', 'red'); 
      });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Venkata!  My setup has @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) inside the <head></head> already. Then I add another into the <body></body> it doesn't work.  I also try to removed this line of code inside the <head> and place this on the <body>, the background color didn't turn red, either!

Comment: put some alert in it so that you can see working or not

Comment: There may be other cause to not applying red background to body, you may try with specific property in backgroundobject `$('body').css('backgroundColor', 'red');`

Comment: I place    $(function () { alert('hellooo');}); but it didn't show the alert, either.

Comment: Is that OK if we place @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) inside the <head></head>?

Comment: no it should be at the end of the layout before closing </body>

Comment: @ Venkata, thank you for your help!  But somehow it doesn't work on my case.  First I place `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` before `</body>.  At the bottom of the page I am working on, I place @section Scripts {....}  I write some JQuery such as alert('helloo'); but it doesn't show the alert.  I check you have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`, but in my case, I have a folder named Scripts, which stores jquery-2.1.1.js, then I try to remane "~/bundles/jquery" to `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Scripts")`, but it doesn't work, either.

Comment: @ Venkata, I also have a question at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738909/asp-net-boilerplate-jquery-didnt-go-inside-cshtml-pages).  Please take a look.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

do what the others said, but use

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
</script>
```

Also aspnet boilerplate does not use bundles or a

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in it's layout.

jquery is linked in the layout, so you must use the layout.  The default _ViewStart.cshtml defines the _Layout.cshtml as the layout.

To get the javascript in the scripts section from your cshtml pages (views) to render you must add the

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

to the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Thank you, IceBurg.   I have tried couple styles, but nothing works! The problem is how to add JQuery into ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Comment: OK, I just found out what aspnet boilerplate is.  jQuery is included the default _Layout.cshtml.  Your page must be using this layout.  try adding @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} to the top of your cshtml file.

Comment: @ IceBurg, thank you very much!  I get it works by writing JQuery in a separate file and link it in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml