# ASP.NET Boilerplate How to Add JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a project using ASP.NET Boilerplate. I want to add more functionality by using jQuery.

I try to write a simple code such as (below) to the end of a page (such as Home.cshtml), it looks like no effect at all! Then I try to put this code in Home.js file, nothing happens at all. I also try to create a new .js file with the below code and link it into the project, the body color didn't turn to red!

Please help how to write jQuery on ASP.NET Boilerplate.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css('background', 'red');
});
```

P.S. I recently opened this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723591/adding-jquery-code-to-asp-net-boilerplate), but couldn't get it worked, yet.  Please help

Comment: Don't ask exactly the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `backgroundColor` instead of `background`.

I should also mention that you should include jQuery as follows:

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\script>`

Comment: Thank you Dave, I have tried couple styles, but nothing works!  The problem is how to add JQuery into ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Comment: I added to my answer showing how to include jQuery. Did this help?

Comment: The project has jquery-2.1.1.min.js linked in, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try pressing F12 in your browser and see if there are any JavaScript errors