# ASP.NET Boilerplate JQuery Didn't Go Inside .cshtml pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project using ASP.NET Boilerplate.  I write some JQuery in a separate file and link it in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml.  My JQuery code works such as an alert showing or body's backgrounds'color changing to red. But it is not effected if I want to change some elements inside the page.  For example, the class named "main1" doesn't change to green.
I don't know for sure why?  Please help.  Thanks

Main.cshtml

```
<div ng-controller="app.controllers.views.Main">
      <div class="main1">......</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {

        alert('helloooo');
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');   
        $('.main1').css('background-color', 'green');
    }); // end ready
```

layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/App/Main/js")
</head>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjectClosureApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ProjectClosureAppControllerBase
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            return View("~/App/Main/views/layout/layout.cshtml"); //Layout of the angular application.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to see your `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file.

Comment: Looks like you have some Angular going on as well. Are you sure that the div with class `main1` is actually present on the page when the script runs? Try logging `$('.main1')` to see if jQuery actuall finds a match at that point in your code (`console.log($('.main1'));`)

Comment: Show me the `_Layout.cshtml` where exactly you embed the JavaScript file, Also show me the URL, controller action method. So that I'll explain the cause. Is the `Main.cshtml` loading asynchronously with some ajax call?

Comment: @ Venkata, thank you!  The Main.cshtml loading fine, no problem. I just update my question as you mentioned, please take a look.  Thanks